# combining objects from a map in js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a setup where I'm trying to use a map to return one object of styles. 
Currently my setup is returning an array of objects. I'm not sure if my first approach is a good efficient way to do this.

**Object coming from server needs to map to the the below values.**

```
settings = {engine_background: "Gradient", wheel_padding: "100"}
```

**code in my React component**

```
  const map = {
    engine_background: value => colors[value],
    wheel_padding: value => ({ padding: `${value}px` }),
  };

  const colors = {
    Gradient: {
      background: 'linear-gradient(-80deg, #ffffff, #000000 100%)',
    },
  }; 

 const styles = Object.entries(settings).map(([k, v]) => map[k](v));
```

The top Object.entries(settings) is returning me an array of 2 objects.

```
[{…}, {…}]
0: {background: "linear-gradient(-80deg, #ffffff, #000000 100%)"}
1: {padding: "100px"}
```

This is not exactly what I'm after ideally i'd like my `Object.entries(settings)` to return all the values in map object as one object so I can style my component with them.

**example:**

```
{
  background: "linear-gradient(-80deg, #ffffff, #000000 100%)", 
  padding: "100px",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a reducer over your array of objects for creating a single object:

```
const styles = Object.entries(settings).map(([k, v]) => map[k](v)).reduce((acc, val) => ({
  ...acc,
  ...val
}), {});
```

Just a sample with your final data:

```js
const input = [{background: "linear-gradient(-80deg, #ffffff, #000000 100%)"}, {padding: "100px"}];

console.log(input.reduce((acc, val) => ({
  ...acc,
  ...val
}), {}));
```